# Parsing Representation in Restlet

Tags: java, restlet

I am getting JSONException when I try to put in JSONObject.

```
@Post
public String someCode(Representation rep) throws ResourceException{
    try {
        rep.getText();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error in receiving data from Social", e);
    }   

    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(rep);
        String username = json.getString("username");
        String password = json.getString("password");
        String firstname = json.getString("firstname");
        String lastname = json.getString("lastname");
        String phone = json.getString("phone");
        String email = json.getString("email");

        LOGGER.info("username: "+username); //JsonException
        LOGGER.info("password: "+password);
        LOGGER.info("firstname: "+firstname);
        LOGGER.info("lastname: "+lastname);
        LOGGER.info("phone: "+phone);
        LOGGER.info("email: "+email);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    return "200";
}
```

**ERROR LOG:**

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["username"] not found.
    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:516)
    at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:687)
```

**NOTE:**

When I try to print `rep.getText()`, I get the following data:

```
username=user1&password=222222&firstname=Kevin&lastname=Tak&phone=444444444&email=tka%40gmail.com
```

Comment: The content type of the response seems to be rather `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then `application/json`

Answer (score 1):

Your rep object isn't a JSON object. I actually think that when you pass it to JSONObject(), it only captures a weird string. I suggest to parse it into an array :

```
Map<String, String> query_pairs = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
String query = rep.getText();
String[] pairs = query.split("&");
for (String pair : pairs) {
    int idx = pair.indexOf("=");
    query_pairs.put(URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(0, idx), "UTF-8"), URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(idx + 1), "UTF-8"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are Receiving in the POST is HTTP Form encoded data not JSON.

Restlet can and does handle these objects natively providing the Form object to interact with them.  rather than `new JSONObject(String)` try `new Form(String)`,  for example:

```
 String data = rep.getText();
 Form form = new Form(data);
 String username = form.getFirstValue("username");
```

I leave the remainder as an exercise to the reader.

Alternatively you will need to adjust the client submitting the data to encode it in JSON see http://www.json.org/ for the description of this syntax.

For reference the `Form` class is `org.restlet.data.Form` in the core Restlet library.

Comment: `form.getFirstValue("username")` is giving null. I am calling the URL with Content Type as `application/json` and json in the content body.

Comment: @MyGod I ran the above code lines with the input string you suggest is coming it output `user1`. One thing with Restlet can be that calling getText() twice can give null object the second time.... as it will not always read the stream twice.   rather than pass in the Representation pass in the result from `getText()`....  You may be sending JSON but that's not what appears to be arriving here, I am unable to tell from the current information what may be converting it along the way.